# Changing old values and new values

Tags: vba, excel, selectionchanged

I have this code that I am using to call old and new values. However I am now having a issue where if the user simply highlights a and hits delete it will run and note that change, however it will run a number of more instances of that same request for some reason. Is there a way so that it will only run the one time?
Thanks

```
Public OldValues As New Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Sheets("Pagination").Range("J11") <> "Yes" Then Exit Sub

    'Copy old values
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        OldValues.Add c.Value, c.Address
    Next c
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Sheets("Pagination").Range("J11") <> "Yes" Then Exit Sub

    On Local Error Resume Next  ' To avoid error if the old value of the cell address you're looking for has not been copied
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        Sheets("corrections").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).Value = Now & " Sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & " Cell " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " has a new value of " & c.Value & "; old value was " & OldValues(c.Address)
    Next c
    'Copy old values (in case you made any changes in previous lines of code)
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    For Each c In Target
        OldValues.Add c.Value, c.Address
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'highlights a'? what do you mean by 'more instances'? Possibly the problem could be solved in the way described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405206/2143262).

Comment: if you hit delete on a cell B5 for example this is what you get           10/9/2013 9:41:15 AM Sheet UCF (2) Cell B5:AE5 has a new value of ; old value was 5
10/9/2013 9:41:15 AM Sheet UCF (2) Cell B5:AE5 has a new value of ; old value was 
10/9/2013 9:41:15 AM Sheet UCF (2) Cell B5:AE5 has a new value of ; old value was 
10/9/2013 9:41:15 AM Sheet UCF (2) Cell B5:AE5 has a new value of ; old value was

Comment: the solution is in my link or in the answer below...

Comment: I added that im still getting the same result.

Comment: and that should say highlights a cell and presses delete without actually entering the cell.

Comment: add toggle break at the beginning of your `change event sub` and try to debug your code with `F8 key`... step-by-step, hopefully you will figure it out in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the beginning of the `Worksheet_Change` event, and then back to `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of it.

EDIT: I can't recreate your problem myself, and since the macro isn't making changes on the same sheet, the above solution shouldn't make a difference. Do you have any other `Worksheet_Change` events on the "corrections" sheet where you need to disable the events like this perhaps?

---

`Application.EnableEvents` should also be added to other functions
which may afftect any cell in sheet which has the `worksheet_change` event.

For example even if the value of Cell A1 changes the worksheet_change event will be called.